# Quickest way to change "Output Device" while html5 video is playing?

Tags: audio

While playing `html5` I am unable to reliably change the *Output Device*:

- changing the *Output Device* while the `html5` is playing never works.
- pausing the `html5` playback, and changing the *Output Device* setting never works.
- waiting until the `html5` finishes, then changing the *Output Device* sometimes works.

Once I start playing an `html5` file, the only sure fire way to change the *OutputDevice* is:

1. pause the `html5` player;
2. launch *iTunes* or *QuickTime* and start playing something;
3. change the *Output Device*;
4. stop playing video / music on *iTunes* or *QuickTime*;
5. un-pause the `html5` player.
6. the sound for the `html5` player is now coming out of the correct *Output Device* setting.

So, what is the quickest way to change the *Output Device* while an `html5` video is playing?

[using *OSX v10.11* with *Chrome v47.0*]

Answer (score 1):

To change the audio output for a HTML5 video you should use its `sinkId` property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/sinkId and set it to `MediaDeviceInfo.deviceid` values returned from `MediaDevices.enumeratedDevices()`.